# How can we manage session in the asp.net mvc and core?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, session

I want to implement in the asp.net core mvc. If anyone know then let me know.

Comment: I guess this link helps you out. 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-session-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion. It's very helpful to us.

```
    const string SessionName = "_Name";  
    const string SessionAge = "_Age";  
    public IActionResult Index()  
    {  
        HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionName, "Jarvik");  
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(SessionAge, 24);  
        return View();  
    }  

    public IActionResult About()  
    {  
        ViewBag.Name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionName);  
        ViewBag.Age = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionAge);  
        ViewData["Message"] = "Asp.Net Core !!!.";  

        return View();  
    }
```